# ios locationInView not show correct log when I click direct view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I feel strange, I have dark view(darkScreenView) and green view.

I using the

```
 -(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
     UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
     CGPoint touchViewPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

      NSLog(@"[self.darkScreenView pointInside:touchViewPoint withEvent:event]:%d",[self.darkView pointInside:touchViewPoint withEvent:event]);
 }
```

When I click on the dark view or green view,

The Log still show 1. why?

I click on the green view should show log 0, but I still get the log result 1.

[image]

[image]

I am using xcode 6.3.1.

Have anyone know what problem in this situation?

Thank you~

Comment: The code you shared, handles both cases for dark and green view?

Comment: Can you NSLog the CGPoint result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchViewPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    CGPoint  pointOfDarkView = [touch.view convertPoint:touchViewPoint toView:self.darkview];
    NSLog(@"[self.darkScreenView pointInside:touchViewPoint withEvent:event]:%d",[self.darkview pointInside:pointOfDarkView withEvent:event]);
```

**Your problem:**

`touchViewPoint` is relative to `touch.view` coordinate

You have to convert point to **darkview coordinate** first,then you can use `pointInside:pointOfDarkView`

Answer (score 0):

Try to get touch for different views..

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
  UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
  if (touch.view==GREEN_VIEW)
  {
    //Write your code for green view here
  }
  else if(touch.view==DARK_VIEW)
  {
    //Write your code for dark view here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your touchViewPoint's location is relative to the touched view. So get location relative to self.darkView like below.

```
CGPoint touchViewPoint = [touch locationInView: self.darkView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem change to View you are referring to.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
     UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
     CGPoint touchViewPoint = [touch locationInView:darkView];   <----- Problem

      NSLog(@"[self.darkScreenView pointInside:touchViewPoint withEvent:event]:%d",[self.darkView pointInside:touchViewPoint withEvent:event]);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I resolve using @WenchenHuang answer.:P